# cancel a submit in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, scrollto

im doing a form validation and I want to validate the input fields when "on submit" if error Im using jquery.scrollTo to go to error:

```
$('#form_inscripcion').submit(function() {
    //se traen todos los inputs del formulario
    var $inputs = $('#form_inscripcion :input');

    $inputs.each(function() {
        var encontro_error = validar($(this)); //uses dependence ok
        if (encontro_error){
            $.scrollTo( 'input#'+$(this).attr('id'), 800 ); //go to error
            return false; // dont submit!... but seems not enter here :(
        }
    });

});
```

The problem is, when error returned doesnt cancel the submit, doesnt run `return false;` line.

It works OK when

```
<form id="form_inscripcion" name="form" method="post" action="some" onsubmit="return false">
```

But so, will never submits. I hope you understand me :) thanks :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would use `e.preventDefault()` like this:

```
$('#form_inscripcion').submit(function(e) { 
     //se traen todos los inputs del formulario
     var $inputs = $('#form_inscripcion :input');

     $inputs.each(function() {
        var encontro_error = validar($(this)); //uses dependence ok
        if (encontro_error){
            $.scrollTo( 'input#'+$(this).attr('id'), 800 ); //go to error
            e.preventDefault(); // Cancel the submit
            return false; // Exit the .each loop
        }
     });
});
```

Just be sure to supply the `e` parameter to the submit function call (first line in the code block).

Answer (score 6):

You are returning from `#each` function, not `#submit`. Do something like this instead:

```
$('#form_inscripcion').submit(function(e) {
        //se traen todos los inputs del formulario
        var $inputs = $('#form_inscripcion :input');
        var returnVal = true;
        $inputs.each(function() {
                var encontro_error = validar($(this)); //uses dependence ok
                if (encontro_error){
                        $.scrollTo( 'input#'+$(this).attr('id'), 800 ); //go to error
                        returnVal = false;
                        return false; // returning false here breaks out of $.each.
                }
        });
        return returnVal;
});
```

You could also do `e.preventDefault()` to stop the form from being submitted.