# ZendFramework Ajax jQuery post

Tags: jquery, ajax, zend-framework, http-post

Hello i got a question about jQuery ajax post request in ZendFramework here is my jquery:

```
$("input[type=image].addToCartButton").click(function() {
    var productId = $(this).attr("id");

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        url: "http://localhost/ZendProjects/essence/essenceZP/public/order",
        data: {
            id: productId
        },
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });

});
```

and here is my code in ZendFramework Order Controller:

```
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
        $test = 'testing ajax content';
        $this->view->test = $test;
    } else {
        $test = 'testing non-ajax content';
        $this->view->test = $test;
    }
```

in firebug console i get an error but cant see where is the error because it shows for 0.5 sec and hide.. any ideas? The idea is when you click the button to send productId to the order controller and put it in session array, but for now only testing the ajax request..

markup:

```
    <form action="" method="post">
        <label for=".productQuantity" style="float: left;margin-top:7px;margin-left: 5px">Количество</label>
        <input class="productQuantity" name="productQuantity" type="number" value="1" min="1" max="1000" style="width: 50px;float: left;margin-left: 7px" />
        <input type="image" id="<?php echo $product->id; ?>" name="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'order', 'action' => 'add-to-cart'), 'default', true) ?>" src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl('images/cartPut.png'); ?>" style="margin-left: 13px;" />
    </form>
```

Comment: i think that that button is doing postback and cancelling ajax request.. post the button markup

Comment: @AshirvadSingh here is my markup

Comment: @FretwoakDukov try this  `<form action="javascript:void(0)" method="post">` or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773852/cancel-a-submit-in-jquery

Comment: thank you @keyne !!!! with javascript:void(0) worked ! :]] can you explain me what happened actually?

Comment: @FretwoakDukov I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that when you click on the submit button the ajax call is triggered at the same time the form is submitted.

You may be wondering why the form is being submitted if there's no `action=""`.

The thing is, when the action attribute  is blank it assumes that it's on the same page. I mean, if you're on `localhost/index.php` than `action=""` = `action="localhost/index.php"`

So, you must disable the form submit by adding  `action="javascript:void(0)"`.

You can also use jQuery for this:

[cancel a submit in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773852/cancel-a-submit-in-jquery)

Or even plain javascript (return false to the submit event)